# How to find the minimum length

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have an X*Y by X*Y vector b (a 2d array/matrix). Each entry in this vector has a list whose length can go from 1 to X*Y elements. I would like to loop through all elements of the vector and find out the row and column of the vector that has the minimum length list (or if there are more than one return one of them or all of them is also good).

I started out with the following (incomplete code)

```
 (define (find-minimum-row-col b X Y)
  (for*/first ([row (* X Y)]
               [col (* X Y)]               
               #:when (< ( length (vector-ref (vector-ref b row) col))) the-min-sofar))
    (cons row col)))
```

I am not sure how to keep track of the running minimum and corresponding coordinates in a functional way (i.e. without using set! on the-min-sofar variable)

Comment: You should provide a sample input of the data expected by the procedure, you just changed the question to something different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (find-minimum-row-col a)
  (for*/fold ([the-min '(0 . 0)])
             ([row (in-range (vector-length a))]
              [col (in-range (vector-length (vector-ref a 0)))])
    (if (< (length (vector-ref (vector-ref a row) col))
           (length (vector-ref (vector-ref a (car the-min)) (cdr the-min))))
        (cons row col)
        the-min)))
```

The trick was to use [`for*/fold`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for*%2Ffold%29%29) to accumulate the result of iteration in the `the-min` variable, and update it as needed. We don't have to pass the dimensions of the matrix, all this works as long as the matrix is non-empty and all rows have the same number of columns. For example:

```
(find-minimum-row-col '#(#((1) (2 2) (3 3 3))
                         #((2 2) (1) (3 3 3))
                         #((2 2) () (2 2))))
=> '(2 . 1)
```